# JSTL сделать checkbox checked

Tags: java, servlet, jstl

Есть набор checkbox в jstl:

```
<c:forEach var="type" items="${types}">
   <label class="checkbox"><input value="${type}" type="checkbox" name="type">${type}</label>
</c:forEach>
```

Надо с помощью сервлета и jstl в ответе показать какие checkbox отметил пользователь, когда отправлял форму. То есть сделать checked те, что отметил пользователь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `c:if` для проверки равенства пользовательского значения и значения переменной `type`. Если совпадает, выводится input с checked, если нет - без него.  Если пользовательских значений несколько, надо проверять содержится ли среди них текущее значение переменной `type`.